# Cannot change UI language in firefox

Tags: firefox, language-support

I got installed Ubuntu with preinstalled Firefox. I'd like to have Firefox with English UI language. However, I got a Firefox with Russian UI. System language in my Ubuntu is English. I tried reinstall Firefox (from Ubuntu Software Center and via `apt-get install firefox`). I tried `apt-get install firefox-locale-en` and set `general.useragent.locale` form `ru` to `en-US`. However, always I receive Firefox in Russian. I know I can download `*.tar.bz2` from http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/

However, I'd like to know *How to persuade Ubuntu Software Center to install English version of Firefox (or via `apt-get install firefox`)?*

Comment: You can change to English from preference option on your existing Firefox.

Comment: Thank you. However, it didn't help

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your display language is not set correctly. Please go to `System Settings -> Language Support`, use that interface to change the language to something else but English, and then back to English. Then relogin, and also Firefox ought to be in English.